# js create object from static method

Tags: javascript, oop

Good afternoon! I have some object as "Coordinates" and i can call this from constructor with two parameters (x, y). But i want use another way, call constructor from static method without parameters (generated random)

```
/**
 * @param {int} x
 * @param {int} y
 * @constructor
 */
var Coordinates = function (x, y) {

    if (!(x >= 0 && y >= 0)) {
        throw new Error('Coordinates is not correctly!');
    }

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    Coordinates.generateRandom = function () {
        var randomX = Math.round(Math.random() * 500);
        var randomY = Math.round(Math.random() * 500);
        return new Coordinates(randomX, randomY);
    };

    this.toString = function () {
        return this.x + ', ' + this.y;
    };
};

//var position = new Coordinates(114, 12); // first way

var position = Coordinates.generateRandom(); // or second way
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7mh770y0/2/

Answer (score 0):

So you just want `Coordinates` to have the static method `generateRandom()`? Then simply move that method out of your class definition (see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2kL4cuv4/)):

```
/**
 * @param {int} x
 * @param {int} y
 * @constructor
 */
var Coordinates = function (x, y) {
    if (!(x >= 0 && y >= 0)) {
        throw new Error('Coordinates is not correctly!');
    }

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.toString = function () {
        return this.x + ', ' + this.y;
    };
};

Coordinates.generateRandom = function () {
    var randomX = Math.round(Math.random() * 500);
    var randomY = Math.round(Math.random() * 500);
    return new Coordinates(randomX, randomY);
};

var position = Coordinates.generateRandom(); // or second way
console.log(position);
```

Example output of Chrome's console for the above code:

```
Coordinates
    toString: function () { ...
    x: 226 y: 132
    __proto__: Coordinates ...
```